# Python - match the last word and delete from previous line

Tags: python, match

I am trying to match the last word and delete from previous line.

```
import re

# regex to select words with _-
line = re.compile('s/^(\w+(?:[-_]\d+)?)\n(?=.*\1\b)//gm;')

here_text = '''befall_fallen-fell
               closing-round
               Line - Eddying, dizzying, closing-round
               laughter-laugh_laugh
               Line - With soft and drunken laughter-laugh_laugh
               laughter-laugh_laugh
               befall_fallen-fell
               Line - Veiling all that may befall_fallen-fell'''
```

Input

```
befall_fallen-fell
closing-round
Line - Eddying, dizzying, closing-round
laughter-laugh_laugh
Line - With soft and drunken laughter-laugh_laugh
laughter-laugh_laugh
befall_fallen-fell
Line - Veiling all that may befall_fallen-fell
```

Output - trying

```
befall_fallen-fell
Line - Eddying, dizzying, closing-round
Line - With soft and drunken laughter-laugh_laugh
laughter-laugh_laugh
Line - Veiling all that may befall_fallen-fell
```

Not sure how to start.

Comment: Does the last word always occur the same number of times in the previous line?

Comment: I don't understand how the input becomes the output. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: no, I am expecting just once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following PCRE regex should work :

```
match \b(\S+)\b(.*\n.*\b\1)$
replace by \2
flags : [m]ulti-line and [g]lobal
```

Or, in python :

```
re.sub(r'\b(\S+)\b(.*\n.*\b\1)$', r'\2', here_text, flags=re.M)
```

You can try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WhbNDX/1) or [ideone](https://ideone.com/LsCJ4x).

Note that a line whose last word was removed in its previous line won't be matched a second time :

```
a
b a
b
```

will be substituted into

```
 
b a
b
```

rather than

```
 
a
b
```

Comment: @Arif oh yeah, I thought this was what you needed. I'll update my answer and notify you with another comment. You might also want to update your question, because you only specify "the last word" which makes it sound like it's the last word of the text rather than the line.

Comment: @Arif updated, but doesn't handle empty lines removal. I suggest you do it separately because I don't think there's a clean way to do it in this regex.

Comment: @Arif I've also added a note you should see if you haven't. This problem can't be solved in regex, you would need to reset the pointer of your regex engine to the start of the last matched line before matching again to solve it. Can definitely be done, but I won't go in the details if you don't need that

Comment: in the same regex how can I ignore the last word if it's ends with let's say laughter-laugh_laugh fades / ends etc. In this case I want to Ignore "fades" or "ends" and only look for "laughter-laugh_laugh".

Comment: @Arif what's the criteria? containing at least a dash and an underscore?

Comment: @Arif Might is not enough. "fades" might include `-` and `_`, it just doesn't. Did you mean "Should" ? If so, replace `\S+` by `\S+[-_]\S+`

Comment: for "laughter-laugh_laugh ends" or "laughter-laugh_laugh fades", while ignoring ends and fades, "laughter-laugh_laugh" might include (- or/and _)

Comment: yes but what's the rule behind ignoring "fades" and "ends" ? Is it because they're too small? Is it because they don't contain `u` ? or because they end in `s` ?

Comment: @Arif do you mean the two specific words "fades" and "ends" maybe? In this case, use `\b(\S+)\b(.*\n.*\b\1(?:fades|ends)?)$`

Comment: yes, I want to ignore just those two words "fades" and "ends"

Comment: \b(\S+)\b(.*\n.*\b\1(?:fades|ends)?)$ <br>
laughter-laugh_laugh <br>
Line - Veiling all that may laughter-laugh_laugh ends <br>
..... couldn't match    laughter-laugh_laugh

Comment: it worked. Had to add the space   - \b(\S+)\b(.*\n.*\b\1(?: fades| ends)?)$. Thank you.